# Adding a Computer to an Azure Active Directory domain using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication

I have an Azure AD domain that I want to add computers to. I have a base account that I log in to before we ship the computer. Is there a PowerShell method to accomplish this with no active user input?

I have tried the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet and that doesnt seem to be what I want.

Comment: Your question-title says "Adding a User" but your post body says you want to "add computers" - so what is it?. Also, you seem to think Azure AD is somehow equivalent to on-prem Active Directory insofar as you discuss _computer accounts_ but on the contrary: AzureAD doesn't have `MACHINENAME$`-style _computer accounts_ (though [it does have "Registered" and "Joined" devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/concept-azure-ad-join)). Remember that AzureAD is just MS's marketing brand for their cloud-y federated-authX system, it is nothing like on-prem AD.

Answer (score 0):

> Adding a Computer to an Azure Active Directory domain using powershell.

Thanks to `Dai` for suugesting the same point.

In order to add the computers to the `Azure AD domain`, you first have to join the devices to the `Azure AD domain`, and then the devices will reflect in `Azure AD Devices`

Here is a **PowerShell** script to join the device to the `Azure AD` domain using the `AADLoginForWindows extension`

> **Note:** The [Connect-AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/connect-azuread?view=azureadps-2.0#description) cmdlet connects an authenticated account to use for Azure Active
> Directory not Domain Joining.

**Powershell command:**

```
Set-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName "<resource-Group-Name" -VMName "venkat-vm" -Location "East Us" -Publisher "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory" -ExtensionName "AADLoginForWindows" -ExtensionType "AADLoginForWindows" -TypeHandlerVersion "0.4"
```

Once you enable the extension, the device is automatically added to the **Azure AD** domain, and it will be displayed in **Azure AD Devices**.

Extension is created successfully.

[image]

The device is successfully added to **Azure AD** after enabling the extension as below.

[image]

Reference: [Installing AADLoginForWindows on VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmextension?view=azps-10.1.0)